# What is Very inefficient rules in css

Tags: css

I ran a speed test on Google and I got some good grades and bad grades for my CSS. The bad grades are due to inefficient CSS. What is that? And how can I rectify it?

```
Very inefficient rules (good to fix on any page):
#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after    Tag key with 4 descendant selectors
#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after    Tag key with 4 descendant selectors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers parse CSS-Selectors from right to left. So CSS gets parsed faster, if you have less descendant selectors.

> Descendant selectors are inefficient because, for each element that
>   matches the key, the browser must also traverse up the DOM tree,
>   evaluating every ancestor element until it finds a match or reaches
>   the root element. The less specific the key, the greater the number of
>   nodes that need to be evaluated.

[Use efficient CSS selectors](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors)

---

Related:

[Optimize css vs Google page speed is messing with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612555/optimize-css-vs-google-page-speed-is-messing-with-me)

[Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why)